# Setting columnCount in Magento 1.9 RWD

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, rwd-theme, grid-layout

Is there an actual way to handle the columnCount in Magento's 1.9 RWD theme?

It is not possible to use `addColumnCountLayoutDepend` in `layout.xml` to set the column counts depending on the page layout in this theme and is only used to set the maximum columns.

I can manually set `$_columnCount = 2;` in the `list.phtml` and whilst `$_columnCount;` outputs 2, the columns on the front end don't actually change.

I see that the widths (%) for the `<li>` items are all hardcoded in `styles.css` to 4 decimal places - surely there is a way to handle this without altering all the widths in the stylesheet to get the amount of products per row you want in your grid?

Even if it were a case of altering all the widths, how do you get this perfect with 4 decimal places like so:-

```
width: 30.8642%;
margin-right: 3.7037%;
```

I'm sure I must be overlooking something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I've figured it out...

The class gets changed depending on the columnCount, i.e:-

```
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-4-col">
```

And the default styles only cater for 4, 5 and 6 columns so the styles get applied on these as expected but as I was trying to change to a two column layout, there was no styles for this the class `products-grid--max-2-col`.

In my case, it is just case of creating a set of styles for a two column layout.

Hope that helps others if they struggle with this.

In terms of setting columnCount, it was still possible to set this in `list.phtml` with something such as:-

```
switch ($pageLayoutRootTemplate) {
case 'page/1column.phtml':
    $_columnCount = 4;
    break;

case 'page/1col-split-2col.phtml':
    $_columnCount = 2;
    break;  

case 'page/2columns-left.phtml':
    $_columnCount = 4;
    break;

case 'page/2columns-right.phtml':
    $_columnCount = 2;
    break;

case 'page/3columns.phtml':
    $_columnCount = 2;
    break;

default:
    $_columnCount = 2;
    break;
}
```

And then comment out:-

```
$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();
```

Answer (score 10):

To set the column count for a particular category, select that category in the backend under Manage Categories. Then select the Custom Design tab—here, add in the following code and modify as needed:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Useful, thanks for adding this to the discussion.

Comment: @david-sinclair, very useful. thank you David. I can made custom layout with that from inside Category Custom Layout Update for Custom Design