# new products on home page magento CE1.9 with rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, products, rwd

having used the following code in the home page cms screen

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

this displays the new products on the home page no problem, when the screen is full width, with one exception, it doesnt centralise them on the screen
[image]

Also the rwd theme is totaly responsive which is awesome, except for this new products block. you can see when you shrink the screen size down (or look on tablets or mobiles) the layout is totaly broken

[image]
[image]

anyone got any ideas how i can fix this, i just want 4 products displayed and to be responsive like the rest of the site

any help much appreaciated.
thanks

Comment: Can you share the URL of the site in question? Have you defined a column count (products per row) at all - either in the template file or via XML update (`<action method="setProductsCount"><count>3</count></action>`)?

Comment: http://www.bos2.co.uk/giftskingdom/    Here is the site tempory while we build it

Comment: Your new products on the homepage are set to 5 per row (there is only 4 products there). Subsequently, the styling for 5 columns is being used `products-grid products-grid--max-5-col`.

Comment: even if i set i nthe admin the numbers, i.e. 4,8,16,20 etc, its makes no difference for me. Is there something i am missing with this then, how can i get it to use max-4-col then, if there is one

Comment: That setting doesn't control the column count. Check out [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25324/setting-columncount-in-magento-1-9-rwd) instead.

Comment: Found a soultion that seems so simple i had to post it here so this would help others...  in /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtemplate/template/catalog/product/new.phtml

in line 30 change the <?php echo $_columnCount; ?> to 4